# How to write correct query to get not deleted rows?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `users` table and I use `softDeletes()` in my table. Also I have `candidates` table where have foreign key (`user_id`) to `users` table.

Generaly how I can get candidates which users is not deleted?

Here my code for get candidates with not deleted users:

```
$candidates = Candidate::all();
$activeCandidates = [];
foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
    if($candidate->user) {
        $activeCandidates[] = $candidate;
    }
}
```

Can be solved my problem without looping with subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`has()` is to filter the selecting model based on a relationship. So, it acts very similarly to a normal WHERE condition. If you just use `has('relation')` that means you only want to get the models that have at least one related model in this relation.

```
$candidates = Candidate::has('user')->get();
```